# F# outputting variables from a function to use in C#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I an writing maths function in f# to be so they can be called by C# code.

I have written the following which is a confidence interval calculator for some sample which has success events. The function which will be called is the ConfidenceIntervalCalculator with the two variables x being number of success and n being sample size.

I want to output all three variables upper limit, lower limit and conversion. What would be the best way to output these so C# could use these?

(I have currently output it as a list but this was to check the functions are actually working.)

Also any comments on actually improve the function is appreciated.

```
open System
#light

// Calculates the conversion rate P hat

let phat (x : float) (n : float) = x / n 

// Calculates the interval based on a 95% confidence level using Binomial proportion confidence interval

let binomialconf (n : float) (phat : float)  = 1.96 * sqrt ((1.00/n)*(phat)*(1.00-(phat)))

// Calculates outputs conversion rate with lower and upper interval confidence limit

let interval (x : float) (n : float)  (inter : float) = [for i in  [-1.00 .. 1.00] -> (phat x n + i * inter) * 100.00 ]

//Piping all functions together to use as one complete function. 

let ConfidenceIntervalCalculator (x : float) (n : float) =  phat x n |>  binomialconf n |> interval x n
```

Comment: Sorry just to say I am new to f#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function returns exactly 3 values you can use a tuple.

Other options are:

- a record which will be seen as a class in C#
- a return value and the other 2 by reference
- a function that will compute the 3 values, that is CPS style.

Comment: Thanks I like the Idea of using a record but will try all of them for experience.